# Phrase/word for situation of too many theorists/teachers but too few skilled workers in the economy

Tags: expressions, word-phrases

Word/phrase expressing the situation where there is an abundance of teachers/theorists but not enough skilled workers?

Answer (score 2):

## Too many chiefs and not enough Indians

From [Idioms at The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/too+many+chiefs+and+not+enough+Indians).

This idiom indicates that the ratio of managers to workers is too high. By extension, it could mean that there are too many teachers / theorists compared to the students / front line.

Comment: It is a great if somewhat dated saying, but I think more implies that everyone wants to be the boss (the chief) and no-one wants to take orders.  Theorists are not necessarily in charge of anything; they are just not getting their hands dirty with the work of doing.

Comment: I respectfully disagree; the proverb has more to do with the imbalance of bosses to workers rater than the desire to be a boss. And of course it's a stretch that theorists are not actually in charge. That's why an idiom was employed.

Comment: I think the idiom is relevant, but maybe somehow sensitive in the present time context.